# Wix bootstrapper hangs up Windows10 Version 1909

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have developed a Wix setup which is started by a managed bootstrapper (burn) which also installs some prerequisites. Everything works fine until the Windows 10 release of version 1909.

Every time I press the **install** button the setup hangs up after the dialog which is asking for admin rights. The logger displays these last lines.

**Log:**

[1A3C:0E38][2020-01-27T13:23:22]i201: Planned package: VC12Redistx64, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: None, cache: Yes, uncache: Yes, dependency: None

[1A3C:0E38][2020-01-27T13:23:22]i201: Planned package: MainSetup, state: Absent, default requested: Present, ba requested: Present, execute: Install, rollback: Uninstall, cache: Yes, uncache: No, dependency: Register

[1A3C:0E38][2020-01-27T13:23:22]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0

[1A3C:0E38][2020-01-27T13:23:29]i010: **Launching elevated engine process.**

If I click twice on the hanging application it crashes completely. There is also a error in the event log but it is not really useful. It only says that the application hanged up.

I have found out one interesting thing. This only appears when I have turned on the UAC. The level doesn't make a difference. Only if I turn off UAC completely it works as excepted.

Has anyone a explanation for this behavior? If I use a earlier version of Windows 10 there is no problem. Has Microsoft changed something in Version 1909 concerning a installer?

Comment: **`1)`** Did you test on another machine / virtual to verify that the problem is not machine-specific? You might want to try using a different user account as well. **`2)`** I would ***procmon.exe*** the process to see what is going on if it is a problem seen across different machines. [Some debugging tips and resource links here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25005864/129130).

Comment: Maybe try the ***`"Generic Tricks"`*** section of the link above.

Comment: **1:** Yes, I have set up multiple virtual machines with different versions of Windows 10. The issue is only reproduceable in version 1909. **2.** Thanks for the tip, i will give it a try.